# Modal popup is not working in hierarchical component structure angular-bootstrap-md

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a hierarchical structure of components like

Agent

task-list (component: this also using the shared task-list-table component)

task-type (component)

preview-task (modal component)

agent.component.html (task-type, task-list and preview-task are used as a reference in this component)

Shared

task-list-table (there is a button View in this component which shows the modal popup when user click)

It's not working/showing the modal popup when I clicked on the button. I used the reference from this link for angular-bootstrap-md i.e https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/modals/basic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the modal in this scenario seems to be wrong. Use dynamic modal instead. Here's link to the documentation on implementing and using dynamic modal: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/modals/basic/#dynamic .

Mark this answer as accepted, if it works.

Comment: May be yes, the way i am implementing it not the correct because of the modal html i.e already available in the link that you shared and i.e the old way of using it. Using it in a dynamic way is the correct one. Though I made some other changes/entry to the NgModule where I am implementing it then its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

1) Placed your model popup html to Agent  or either parent component.

2) Create a service which would publish notification on button click. Raise  or emit event  on your button click of task-list-table or child component.

3) Parent component subscribe to service and  a handler on parent component open model popup.

Comment: Can you please add some example using service to subscribe the component and show the modal popup.